# Customize the caldroid calendar

Tags: android, xml, calendar, customization, caldroid

I want the calendar like headout android app,Like when user will click on less date calendar can be expanded [expanded calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frteq.png) and when user will click on less dates calendar should collapsed to single row like [collapsed calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85rBL.png)

I am using caldroid calendar,with this I am able show only expanded view of calendar not collapsed view.I tried to set the height of caldroid calendar but whole dates are not visible.Please help me

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read How to Ask- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Atf I edited can you help me now